# Excel Pivot charts: resizing a pivot chart

Tags: excel, pivot-table, business-intelligence

I created a pivot chart like so:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7blnq1s7c4uv1di/pie.png

The nationality legend was smaller than this but i streched it more so it can show all the legends, the only problem is that now the legend overlaps the chart and I cant seem to resize or move the chart area itself.. So i can either have the full chart but half the legends missing or either stretch the legend and have it overlap the chart area... both of them are a problem.. is there a way i could create the chart and make it automatically show all the legends or perhaps move the chart to the left?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that makes the entire chart box larger, so the chart area inside becomes larger but so does the legend area and the overlapping is still there

Answer (score 0):

Seems not to work for OP (maybe because not using Excel 2007?) but for me with a PivotChart like so:

[image: SO21535156 first example]

dragging the indicated handle to the right (and a little repositioning to make room for the entire legend) changes the display to:

[image: SO21535156 second example]